# How Convert SMS actions to interface?

Tags: web-services, aspnetboilerplate

Suppose that we have difference SMS provider for each tenant (each tenant have their own SMS provider that wants to send SMS thorough those provider) How can we implement this situation in ASPNetBoilerplate?

Comment: I think we must create one DLL with specific interface for each tenant and store in related Database. But where is the location for loading and injecting this DLL in ASPNetBoilerplate template?

Answer (score 0):

If each tenant has only one sms provider then you can create a complex type on Tenant class. If each tenant has more than one sms provider then create TenantSmsProvider entity.

I did not understand why you want to create DLL!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are asking for the Dependency Injection.
You should create a factory (say `ISmsProviderFactory`) that creates sms provider (say `ISmsProvider`) by tenant id (say `GetProviderByTenantId(int tenantId`). This is a common software pattern. Then you can inject `ISmsProviderFactory` and get `ISmsProviderFactory` based on a tenant whenever you need.

Instead of creating a custom factory class, you can use Castle Windsor's API to register dependencies by factory. Thus you can directly inject `ISmsProvider` in your code.

Now, the problem is how to implement `SmsProviderFactory`? There are different approaches depends on your requirement. But this part is out of scope of ABP and you can find many articles on the web.

BTW, if you want to take advantage of ABP's plugin system, then you can design it a bit different: Every plugin dll can add an `ISmsProvider` to a dictionary (where the key of dictionary is tenant id / name) so your factory can pick registered provider for given tenant.